# How to make JLabel not effect size of other elements in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener, layout-manager

my JLabel resizes the JButtons on my GUI I have made here. Is there a way to make the JLabel called answer not resize my buttons? here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class Calc extends JFrame {
    JLabel prompt1, prompt2, answer;
    JTextField field1, field2;
    JButton add, sub, times, div;

    Calc() {
        super("My First Calculator!");
        setSize(500,500);
        setResizable(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();    

        prompt1 = new JLabel("<html><body>1<sup>st</sup></body></body>");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    add(prompt1, c);

    field1 = new JTextField(10);
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    add(field1, c);

    prompt2 = new JLabel("<html><body>2<sup>nd</sup></body></body>");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    add(prompt2, c);

    field2 = new JTextField(10);
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    add(field2, c);

    add = new JButton("+");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    add(add, c);

    sub = new JButton("-");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    add(sub, c);

    times = new JButton("x");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 2;
    add(times, c);

    div = new JButton("<html><body><p>&divide;</p></body></html>");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 3;
    c.gridy = 2;
    add(div, c);

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();

        answer = new JLabel("");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 4;
        add(answer, c);

       event a = new event();
       add.addActionListener(a);
       sub.addActionListener(a);
       times.addActionListener(a);
       div.addActionListener(a);
    }

//    ################ ActionListener ################

    public class event implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            double fnum, snum;
            double ans;

            try {
                fnum = Double.parseDouble(field1.getText());

            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                answer.setText("Illegal Data Entered (Error O1)");
                answer.setForeground(Color.RED);
                return;
            }
            try {
                snum = Double.parseDouble(field2.getText());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e){
                answer.setText("Illegal Data Entered (Error 01)");
                answer.setForeground(Color.RED);
                return;
            }            
            String operation = a.getActionCommand();

            if(operation.equals("+")) {
                ans = fnum + snum;
                answer.setText(fnum + " + " + snum + " = " + ans);
                answer.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            } else if(operation.equals("-")) {
                ans = fnum - snum;
                answer.setText(fnum + " - " + snum + " = " + ans);
                answer.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            } else if(operation.equals("x")){
                ans = fnum * snum;
                answer.setText(fnum + " x " + snum + " = " + ans);
                answer.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            } else if(operation.equals("/")) {
                ans = fnum / snum;
                answer.setText(fnum + " / " + snum + " = " + ans);
                answer.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            }

        } 

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Calc().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

When I run the program it shows like this [image]

and when you enter data and hit a button the buttons change sizes. How do i stop that[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather then having the `JLabel` fill only a single cell, which will effect all the other components in that column, you could adjust the `gridwidth` to allow the answer label to "overflow" into other columns

Perhaps, something like...

```
answer = new JLabel("");
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 4;
c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
add(answer, c);
```

This will allow the answer to completely fill the 4th row, but will be aligned to the left

**Updated**

As Hovercraft has commented, you could also use compound layout managers to fulfill your requirements, adding various elements of the UI to sub panels and then adding them back to the main panel...

Comment: or don't try to use GridBagLayout as a one layout for everything sort of layout.